# How Bohr's model explains the stability of atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, atomic-physics, history, stability

How [Bohr's model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) explains the stability of atoms? From Maxwell's equation, we know that an electron or any other charge will radiate energy on acceleration.
This problem is said to be solved by Bohr without any proper explanation, rather considering stability as an axiom. I don't understand nor did I find anywhere how can this charge not radiate energy while performing any kind of oscillatory motion around a center, which would definitely involve accelerations. It would be helpful even if someone explains how this problem is resolved in modern quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Its is one of the fundamental postulate of the Bohr Model that no radiation is emitted when the electron occupies an allowed orbit.

As unsatisfactory as it is, it was a makeshift solution in an attempt to explain the experimental evidence of it's time, and it worked! It might have even suggested that classical electrodynamics was completely incorrect back in the day.

Using Bohr's model, which required that angular momentum be quantized, we would have found that $l=0$ was a valid solution. Does that mean that the electron is not orbiting in the Bohr model? There clearly were alot of issues with the Bohr model.

In modern quantum mechanics, we would solve for solutions to time-independent Schrödinger equation $$H | \psi \rangle = E | \psi \rangle$$ of a Hydrogen atom. The result would be a eigenstate, independent of time. The use of wavefunctions and its probabilistic interpretation of today has instead taken away meaning from the Bohr model and a literal electron orbit.

Comment: The statement about $l=0$ is unnecessary and incorrect. All solutions of the quantum mechanical problem are stationary, even with $l\ne0$.

Comment: My bad that is true

Comment: So does 0 angular momentum solve our problem?

Comment: Electron are still accelerating and 0 angular momentum doesn't seem to help anyway.

Comment: @YashkalpSharma I have updated my remarks about l=0. Sorry about the confusion i created.

Answer (score 1):

Thing you need to understand is Bohr's orbit is a failure not only when it comes to explain how it does not fall into nucleus radiating energy but also due to Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle.

Bohr's model of atom suggested that electrons are revolving in definite shells so we should be able to calculate the position and momentum of electron but according to heisenberg 's uncertainty principle we can't measure momentum and position the electron simultaneously. If you're able to calculate position there might be uncertainty in momentum and vice-versa.

Edit :- There is nothing like revolving you just calculate the probability density through the Schrodinger Wave Function which leads us to "no probability of electron being in nucleus".

$\psi_{n l m}(r, \theta, \phi)=R_{n}(r) Y_{l m}(\theta, \phi)$. This wavefunction explains it.

You need to drop the "electron is a particle" mindset to understand this. Heisenberg Principle rules that out. This [link](https://nanohub.org/resources/5011/download/zeemansplitting.pdf) might be useful.

Comment: Ok, I understand that, but the real problem remains how will you explain the stability of the atom. Leave Bohr aside, I want to know how does even today one would explain the stability of the atom. knowing classical electrodynamics.

Comment: I happen to be studying the same right now. There is nothing like revolving you just calculate the probability density through the Schrodinger Wave Function which leads us to "no probability of electron being in nucleus".

Comment: @YashkalpSharma That's the catch! You _cannot_ explain the stability of atom using classical physics, even today :) you need quantum mechanics.

Comment: $\psi_{nlm}(r,\theta , \phi)=R_{n}(r) Y_{lm}(\theta \phi )$ @YashkalpSharma
this intimidating looking function is not revealed to us until we clear 12th standard. And it's the most compact form I could right it in.

Comment: But, what about electron's acceleration. I understand that while using quantum mechanics we don't encounter this problem, we are dealing in wavefunctions. But this must be corresponding to the theory previously developed explaining this of which we are only using the end results. I just wish to know the core theoretical principle explaining this.

Comment: You need to drop the "electron is a particle" mindset to understand this.
@YashkalpSharma Heisenberg Principle rules that out.

Comment: @fra_pero I hope we must have a solution to this, would be sad to find you correct :)

Comment: @YashkalpSharma I am sorry but we do not have a solution in classical physics. That was a major success of the theory of quantum mechanics. In any case, the point is exactly that you need to drop the "electron is a particle" concept, as was pointed out in the other comment.

Comment: @YashkalpSharma  this link https://nanohub.org/resources/5011/download/zeemansplitting.pdf will help you understand. If that does not help. Let's move this to chat room.

Comment: @MadameAkira, but considering a charged particle in any another way here (just like a wavefunction as you are hinting) won't be a satisfying approach, I guess:)

Comment: @YashkalpSharma what you are saying is that explain YDSE to me with particle nature. That is not the way.

Answer (score 1):

Bohr in order to explain why the spectrum of light from atoms was not continuous, as expected from classical electrodynamics, but had distinct spectra in frequencies that could be fitted with mathematical series, used a planetary model , imposing [axiomaticaly angular momentum quantization.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html#c4)

[image: bohr mod]

> Although the Bohr model of the atom was shown to have many failures, the expression for the hydrogen electron energies is amazingly accurate. The Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom actually gave the same energies, so the Bohr model was a helpful step along the way to developing a quantum mechanical model for hydrogen.

....

> In the Bohr [model](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Bohr.html#c2), the wavelength associated with the electron is given by the DeBroglie relationship

[image: debrog]

> and the standing wave condition that circumference = whole number of wavelengths.

This standing wave requirement brings in the quantization of angular momentum.

Quantization was at the time used to explain the [black body](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html) radiation graphs. The Bohr model's success in getting the mathematical  [series that described the spectra](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/hydspec.html#c1) showed that this was the way to go.

Have a look at the [history of quantum mechanics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_quantum_mechanics#Overview)